# Jasmine - How can I mock history.pushState and also fake event emission?

Tags: javascript, jquery, testing, mocking, jasmine

I'm writing a library that supports browser navigation with the help of [history.pushState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#The_pushState%28%29.C2.A0method) and also catches the [popstate event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#The_popstate_event) that communicates when navigation takes place in the browser. As I'm trying to write [Jasmine](http://pivotal.github.com/jasmine/) tests for this library, I'm wondering how I can mock `history.pushState` and also fake the emission of the `popstate` signal from `window`? The following code snippets should elucidate the problem:

Library code:

```
var lib = (function() {
    function navigate(path) {
        history.pushState(null, null, path);
    }

    function onPopState(event) {
        if (lib.callback) {
            lib.callback(document.location);
        }
    }

    $(window).bind('popstate', onPopState);

    return {
        navigate: navigate
    };
})();
```

Test code (Jasmine):

```
describe("Test navigate", function() {
    it("Should invoke callback upon state change", function() {
        var invokedWith;
        function callback(url) {
            invokedWith = url;
        }
        lib.callback = callback;
        lib.navigate('/path');
        // Doesn't work, callback invoked asynchronously
        expect(invokedWith).toEqual('/path');
    });
});
```

Basically, I want to mock the `history.pushState` function and emit a fake `popstate` event from `window`, so as to test the `popstate` handling in `lib`.

See also my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aknuds1/fQXkr/) for "working" code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can spy on `history.pushState` like this:

```
spyOn(history, 'pushState');
```

As you use jquery to bind the event you can simply trigger `popstate` by yourself.

```
$(window).trigger('popstate')
```